# Wordpress Media Upload Issue

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Whenever I try to upload image in media section of Wordpress, it gives following error: "Could not insert attachment into the database."

I tried following steps:

1. Increase PHP memory
2. Repair Database
3. Applied define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false ); in wp-config.php

PHP and Wordpress both are latest version. Can anyone please guide me through this as not able to solve this from quite long time ?

Thank you

Comment: Turn on error logging throughout the system to get the real error image. Turn on SQL query logs in WordPress as well. Needs more debugging.

Comment: Does DB type InnoDB or MyISAM affect anything because it is not letting my repair InnoDB type tables ?

Comment: As previously stated, turn on error logging everywhere. WordPress, PHP, Nginx/Apache, etc. See what the specific error is.

Comment: what is the file type of the attachment you are trying to upload? it is probably blocked (like svg might be)

Answer (score 1):

Enable debugging in WordPress to get more information about the error. Add the following lines to your wp-config.php file:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

After enabling debugging, try to upload again and then check the wp-content/debug.log file for any error messages that might provide more information about the problem.